# Why my php code doesnt work?

Tags: php

php is not working in my computer. I have installed Apache server and save the file with .php extension in htdocs but still its not working.

I have written these code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

it shows nothing. I have opened .htaccess file and got,

```
# This folder does not require access over HTTP
# (the following directive denies access by default)
Order allow,deny
```

what can I do now.please help me.

Comment: Have you installed PHP?

Comment: how are u accessing the file via url?

Comment: You don't need the .htaccess file as you have access to the phpmyadmin.conf file.

Comment: Use a browser and enter URL like localhost/{yourfoldername}/{yourfilename}.php and check the output

Comment: No I have not. I just installed Apache server.@ Passerby

Comment: Are you able to open phpmyadmin? are you saving your file as *.php extention. Is apache and mysl are on in xampp panel. If these conditions come true, php will run..

Comment: download xampp and install... use that to run php

Comment: HTML and CSS is working fine but php code is not working like before.@Viswanath Polaki

Comment: HTML and CSS don't need apache to run, they are executed by your browser alone, could you check the apache log please and post the results

Answer (score 1):

Open the Apache server log and take a good look at it.  That's what it's there for.  It logs everything.  Is in /logs in your Apache programs directory.

You either don't have php installed into Apache correctly (likely), don't have Apache set up correctly, or don't have PHP set up correctly.

You'll want to look at conf/httpd.conf for Apache configuration, and php.ini for php configuration.

Sort out Apache first.  Try to serve a simple .htm or .html page.  i.e. put a simple text file with .htm file extension, e.g. myfile.htm, in your DocumentRoot (see conf/httpd.conf) and see if you can browse to it.

You might want to set 'ServerName localhost', and then browse to localhost/myfile.htm

From the Apache log you will also be able to tell if php is loading correctly.  If not  comment out the list of extensions, e.g. extension=php_gd2.dll, and try it again.  I've had it not load because some of the libraries were not present.  If you get it to work with all commented out, then one way or another figure out which ones are causing the trouble and leave them out.

Important: You must shutdown Apache and restart it after any configuration changes.  (Not re-boot, but rather the Apache server monitor widget.)

Also did you install 32 bit versions of both Apache and php?  If you try to mix x64 with x32 it won't work.  And as I recall there are specific recommendations about which versions to use with which at the php download site.  Pay attention to the details there.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to add the php module to apache

a.Running PHP 5 as an Apache Module

To configure Apache to load PHP as a module to parse your PHP scripts, use an ASCII text editor to open the Apache configuration file, "httpd.conf". If you use Apache 1.x, the file is found in "c:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\conf\". Apache 2.0.x users can find it in "C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\conf\" while Apache 2.2.x users can find it in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\". Basically, it's in the "conf" folder of wherever you installed Apache.

Search for the section of the file that has a series of "LoadModule" statements. Statements prefixed by the hash "#" sign are regarded as having been commented out.

If you are using Apache 1.x, add the following line after all the LoadModule statements:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache.dll"
```

If you are using Apache 2.0.x, add the following line after all the LoadModule statements:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
```

If you are using Apache 2.2.x, add the following line instead:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

This steps can be found on this [link](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everybody who tried to give my answer and helped me. It was a surprising experience for me that how quick you answered my question!! It was my ignorance to follow your suggestions. I've solved the problem by installing xampp. Now php is running fine in my computer.I am new in PHP programming and I will ask your help in future also. So be helpful to me always. I will be grateful to you. Thanks again.

Kallol Das,
Bangladesh.